# future light cones and light paths

Tags: gravity, electromagnetic-radiation, spacetime, mass

I understand that an event, in a four dimensional space-time, produces a light cone. As time increases the cones gets larger on either side of the event (past and future). For example the if the sun where to "go out" it would take 8 minuets for the earth to be affected by it simply because it takes approximately 8 minuets for light from the sun to reach the earth due to its location in the future light cone of the event (the sun being the event).

Einstein made a suggestion that space-time is warped (vs flat) by the distribution of mass and energy and that bodies (like earth, jupiter, etc.) are meant to follow straight paths but cannot in a warped space (or appear not to because space is warped). However light supposedly follows these warped paths (called geodesics) as well even tho light is energy.

How can space bend light? and why does light have to follow a specific path which is warped by space? Things with mass (like water) have to go around things (like rocks), but light can go through certain things or expand, but it doesn't move to the side like water does to a rock. Does it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The underlying space is curved.  There is no 'straight' path.  It's like asking why planes have to travel on great arcs to get the shortest path between cities on the Earth's surface, rather than flying on a straight line on a Mercator projection.

Comment: but the earth is round... space is infinite (theoretically)

Comment: so what? and if that is the argument, space is round too near big masses, that roundness is the curvature

Comment: but than where does that path "empty into" if it is bent what happens when it gets around the mass because it cant just fill up the universe. What path does it have to follow after that. plus in an infinite space you should be able to go in a straight line. in fact because thats the shortest distance that's what energy does

Comment: @Luca: yes, but there's more to the curvature of the Earth than the fact that if you go around, you'll come back again--the curvature of the Earth also changes what you mean by a 'straight line'--a non-curving line no longer gives you the shortest distance between two points.  It turns out that general relativity predicts that such a fact also turns out to be true for ay situation where gravity is present.

Comment: @lurscher: yes, that's my point.  Curvature alters the shortest distance paths for everything, even light.  There's no spooky contradiction.

Comment: do we know why? and light expands in all directions (possible) kind of like gas. So how does it follow a single path. It seems like light from a single source would have to exist everywhere simply cause it doesnt "run out" I mean it can kind of thin out but thats only cause it goes somewhere else

Comment: everywhere except black holes

Comment: light also does not have a gravitational attraction so y would it be affected by a curved path

Comment: @luca590: you're exactly right.  Usually, when we talk about light 'travelling on a path', we're talking about light under some sort of geometric optics approximation, where we can think of the light as a single ray that gets bent and moved by the stuff around it.  But you are right to point out that real light spreads out evenly in all directions, gradually filling that space out.  But in this picture, explaining the bending of light by gravity (or a lense), is a bit trickier conceptually, even if, in base, the situation is very close to the geometric optics one.

Comment: @luca590: actually, light does have a gravitational pull, and also, it's affected by the fact that the underlying space is curved.  There IS no straight path.

Comment: how? light does not have mass. I mean its energy and the mass of electrons is so unreasonable its virtually irrelevant

Comment: what can light be attracted to?

Comment: light is not attracted to anything; gravitation doesn't pull matter in the same sense that electromagnetism do, gravitation just curves the space and that curvature applies to every single little thing that needs to travel around. Actually, then a bit later quantum gravity comes and takes a step back again and attempts to say that there is a force in the traditional sense after all that just happens by hocus pocus math to behave in scales above planck just as general relativity, but we can just ignore that fact for the purpose of this discussion

Comment: Energy is equivalent to mass.